# I have the ubuntu iso file. Now what?

Tags: software-installation

My current OS is Windows and I want to start using Ubuntu. After I downloaded Ubuntu, I got a iso file and I have no idea what to do next.

Comment: It is explained better over here than I possibly could: http://askubuntu.com/a/152902/631140

Answer (score 1):

> To try Ubuntu you have to make a bootable flash drive.

Here are the steps:

- Visit [Rofus - Create bootable USB drives](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) and download the software.

  [image: Download option for Rofus]
- Once downloaded & installed it look like this.

  [image: Rofus start screen]
- Now insert you pen-drive (**>2GB**) and select your USB by clicking on **Device** option in **Rofus**.
- Leave all other option as default.
- Now select the `.iso` for Ubuntu that you have downloaded by clicking on disk icon as shown.

  [image: selecting .iso file]
- Now click on **Start** button it will take around 3-4 minutes.
- When your device is ready close **Rofus**.
- At last restart your device **without removing pen-drive**.

> Hey! You can now install\try Ubuntu :)

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest wubi program, place it in same folder as Ubuntu iso file....run it & follow the instructions to install Ubuntu *inside* windows.

Now u can dual boot to windows or Ubuntu as required.

Comment: Wubi!? That is a dead project and wont work with uefi. And it is more than likely he is using W8 or W10 so....

Comment: @Rinzwind Its not exactly dead I recently used it to install Ubuntu 16.04. A bit of google search might help....get the file.